# In C++ How do I compare the size of a character array vs string?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, size, character

I have the following declaration

```
char c[] = "Hello";
string c2 = "Hello";
```

I want to compare a) how many bytes of memory both need and b) the character lengths. 
I know the character arrays add a null terminator at the end of the string where as string data types don't.

Using

```
cout << "The sizeof of c: " << sizeof(c);
cout << "The sizeof of c2: " << sizeof(c2);
```

returns 6 and 4 and I'm not sure why 4 and not 5?
also how does length function compare here ...

When I use the following code

```
cout << "The sizeof of c: " << sizeof(c);
cout <<"The sizeof of c2: " << c2.length();
```

I get 6 and 5 ... but is it comparing the lengths the same way?
Thanks.

Comment: `sizeof(c2) == 4`?? Really? What is the real type of `c2`? It is clearly not an `std::string`

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Why not?  Is there something illegal about a string implementation that holds a solitary pointer to a metadata block, ala pimpl?

Comment: @BenVoigt: I imagine that technically that would be possible, haven't seen any implementation of `std::string` doing that ever though.

Comment: `sizeof` is an compile-time *operator*; not a run-time *function*, and evaluates (at compile-time) as the size of a *type* which can be provide either directly (`sizeof(std::string)`) or via an *expression* result type (`sizeof c2`). Ultimately it is type-based. The difference in your question is due to the difference in *types*. One is a `char[6]`, the other is `string` (which I can only assume is `std::string`, but you'e provided no additional info to confirm/deny that assumption). [**Read this**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) for more info.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: libstdc++-v3 does (Is this the old copy-on-write implementation that is non-conformant since C++11?) : https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h?view=markup

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: pimpl certainly does make move and swap easy.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I was not aware of that :) (i.e. I had not looked into that implementation, but thought I had, I have checked most containers in different implementations, but seem to have skipped that string implementation)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> a) how many bites of memory both need and

You correctly used the sizeof operator that to determine how many bytes the character array occupies.

It is

```
sizeof( c )
```

As for the object of type `std::string` then it occupies two extents of memory. The first one is used to allocate the object itself and the second one is used to allocate the string the object holds.

So

```
sizeof( c2 )
```

will give you the size of the memory occupied by the object.

```
c2.capacity()
```

will give you the size that the object allocated to store the string and maybe some additional characters that will be filled in future.

> When I use the following code cout << "The sizeof of c: " <<
>   sizeof(c); cout <<"The sizeof of c2: " << c2.length();
>
> I get 6 and 5

If you want to compare the strings itself without the terminating zero that the character array has then you should write

```
cout << "The length of c: " << std::strlen(c);
cout <<"The length of c2: " << c2.length();
```

and you will get result 5 and 5.

You could make the following experiment with objects of type  std::string.

```
std::string s;

std::cout << sizeof( s ) << '\t' << s.capacity() << '\t' << s.length() << std::endl;

std::string s1( 1, 'A' );

std::cout << sizeof( s1 ) << '\t' << s1.capacity() << '\t' << s1.length() << std::endl;

std::string s3( 2, 'A' );

std::cout << sizeof( s2 ) << '\t' << s2.capacity() << '\t' << s2.length() << std::endl;

std::string s3( 16, 'A' );

std::cout << sizeof( s3 ) << '\t' << s3.capacity() << '\t' << s3.length() << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof(c)` is the size of the array, which contains the five characters in the literal you initialise it with, plus a zero-valued terminator at the end, giving a total of six bytes.

`sizeof(c2)` is the size of the `string` class, which doesn't tell you anything particularly useful. The class manages a dynamically allocated memory containing the string's characters; that's not part of the `string` object itself.

`c2.length()` is the number of characters in the string managed by `c2`; five characters.

Answer (score 2):

> a) how many bytes of memory both need, and b) the character lengths

- variable 'c' uses 6 bytes on stack  (the 5 letters and the null terminator)
- sizeof(c) = 6,  strlen(c) = 5
- Total bytes of memory needed: 6

---

- if 'c' had 1000 chars,

  - sizeof(c) = 1001, strlen(c) = 1000)
- Total bytes of memory needed: 1001

---

- variable 'c2' uses 4 bytes on stack (I suspect a pointer, but have not confirmed), 
  and at least 5 bytes somewhere else (I think heap).
- sizeof(c2) = 4,  c2.size() = 5,  strlen(c2.c_str()) = 5
- Total bytes of memory needed: 9+  (4 + 5)+

---

- if 'c2' had 1000 chars, i.e. c2.size() == 1000
- 4 bytes on the stack, and
- at least 1000 bytes somewhere else (depending on implementation, probably a few more)
- Total bytes of memory needed: 1004+

NOTE:  std::string is a container. I think such values are not specified,
       and should be considered implementation dependent.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the size of the [] includes the terminating null character, thus 5+1=6 bytes.

The size of the string object returns 4 bytes which probably is the size of the pointer which points to the string object. 32 bits.

In the last case you're using the Length which is programmed to count the number of characters.

Answer (score 0):

Well the size of `c[] = "Hello"` is 6 because the char array needs to allocate 1 more byte of 
memory for the null `\0` character.

the `length()` function returns the number of characters in the string literal.It does not include the null `\0` character while counting.

Comment: *"I want to compare a) **how many bytes of memory** both need, and b) the character lengths"*

Comment: Well both of them need 6 bytes of memory.Its just that `length()` function does not return the size in bytes but rather in the no. of characters present

Answer (score 0):

`std::string`, like `std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr`, and `std::vector`, is a smart pointer plus some extra manipulation member functions.

When you pass one to `sizeof`, you're measuring the size of the smart pointer -- `sizeof (std::string)`, not the content.